# keytool asks for password despite -noprompt and -keypass is set

Tags: bash, keytool

I'm trying to create an installation script, that reads data out of an .ini file and writes it into several configuration files. One step is to create an SSL key via keytool and to request it's certification (create a csr-file). I now have the problem that keytool asks for the password instead of using the provided one (in the variable $keyStorePassword), although i also have activated -noprompt. I would be glad if anyone could help.

```
keytool -genkey -noprompt -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 \
-dname "CN=${HOSTNAME}-${microserviceName}-${environment}, O=${organizationName}, L=${localityName}, S=${stateName}, C=${country}" \
-validity ${validity} -keypass ${keyStorePassword} -keystore ${keyStorePath} -alias ${microserventerviceName}-ssl

keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -file ${microserviceName}.csr -keystore ${keyStorePath} -alias ${microserviceName}-ssl
```

I've already searched the web but the problem doesn't seem to be common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parameters for passwords:

- `-keypass`: The password for the key.
- `-storepass`: The password for the keystore.

Each key entry in a Java keystore has its individual password, so you have to provide both the keystore password and the key password when generating a new key or accessing a key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.  I've tried 

`keytool -genkey -noprompt -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 \ -dname "CN=${HOSTNAME}-${microserviceName}-${environment}, O=${organizationName}, L=${localityName}, S=${stateName}, C=${country}" \ -validity ${validity} -storepass ${keyStorePassword} -keypass testpasswd -keystore ${keyStorePath} -alias ${microserviceName}-sslu` 

`keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -file ${microserviceName}.csr -keystore ${keyStorePath} -alias ${microserviceName}-sslu`  

But it repeatedly asks for a password. (darn formation in comments!)

Comment: @Damian You have to use the two password parameters for the second command too.